# VSCode, Django and javascript: Why does VSCode indicate an error when I use {{ }}?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have the following code that works in my html file:

```
    {% for stocks_and_pair_data in stocks_and_pair_data_list %}
        <script>
            var ctxClose = document.getElementById('ChartOfClosePrices{{ forloop.counter }}');

            new Chart(ctxClose, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: {{stocks_and_pair_data.dates|safe}},
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '{{ stocks_and_pair_data.stock1_name|safe }}',
                        data: {{stocks_and_pair_data.stock1_close_prices|safe}}
                    },{
                        label: '{{ stocks_and_pair_data.stock2_name|safe }}',
                        data: {{stocks_and_pair_data.stock2_close_prices|safe}}
                    }]
                }
            });
        </script>
    {% endfor %}
```

But VSCode indicates the error "Property assignment expected" at 'labels' line and at both 'data' lines, which are where I use double {{ }} without quotes. I can't use quotes there because these are lists, not strings.

Am I doing it wrong, despite of the code working? What should I do to correct it?

Comment: You might get this to work with one of the django plugins, but it's usually not a good idea to mix js and django templates - it gets confusing very fast, and makes it very hard to extract the js into its own file later...

Comment: You are wright. Installing an extension named "Django Templates" made VSCode recognize this synthax. Please, make it an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Ans thanks for the advice to extract the js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code depends on plugins to understand most languages. A django template plugin (e.g. Django, Django Templates, et. al) will fix the issue.

Aside: Do note that mixing Django template language with javascript will potentially make it very difficult to extract the javascript into its own file later (for bundling/transpiling/etc.). It's usually better to feed django data to a javascript function that does the looping.